# c++, sleep, and loops

Tags: c++, linux, sleep

Ok, this is just out of curiousity, but why does the sleep function NOT work in a loop, or how can I Get it to work in a loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
     cout << i << endl; 
     sleep(2); 
}
```

Comment: Ummm...what makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: possibly, its "storing" these sleeps, and , is the example above, will print out 0 1 2 3 4 after 10 seconds is up? IF this is the case, how do I avoid that?

Comment: Looks like it should work to me... Unless of course sleep is the standard function and you have written your own.

Comment: Are you piping the output of this program to another?

Comment: Windows' sleep() takes an interval in *milliseconds* -- you're probably just not noticing a sleep of 2 milliseconds.

Comment: well, Im on a linux platform actually, so sleep is 2 seconds, not 2 milliseconds, and even so, it should still print the numbers, its not even priting the numbers.

Comment: Could you post the entire source file?  The code above works fine on cygwin and OpenBSD but I #include <unistd.h> and <iostream>.

Comment: Also works as expected, with includes on ubuntu, and g++ 4.2.4.

Comment: It works for me. Also, try to post whole source file - it's so tedious having to manually add all those includes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cout` is buffered, meaning its contents aren't always written to the console right away. Try adding `cout.flush()` right before `sleep(2);`

Comment: << endl actually flushes the stream.  It has the same effect as << "\n" << flush.

Comment: Or you can use std::ends to do the same thing without the newline.

Answer (score 1):

If that isn't working for you you could try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

...

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
     cout << i << endl; 
     Sleep(2000); 
}
```

Comment: considering the linux tag on the question, I would assume that including <windows.h> is not an option

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, this program should work correctly. Maybe your std::cout is redirected somewhere else? You don't call the correct sleep() function (but no header provided)? Or other problem? But it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unrolling the loop to see if that behaves the same way?

```
cout << 1 << endl;
sleep(2);
cout << 2 << endl;
sleep(2);
// Etc.
```

Assuming that behaves the same way, even though std::endl is supposed to flush the buffer, it really does look like dave.kilian has the right idea that cout isn't getting flushed until the program (presumably) terminates.

In that case, try doing the std::flush and see if that helps - it's possible you have a bug (missed feature?) in your standard library.

Another thing to try is to redirect the output to a file while watching it with `tail -f` in another window. See if the same delay occurs when redirected.

Finally try playing with the compiler's optimization level and see if that changes the results.

Answer (score 0):

Dave has already given you the answer, so I won't touch on that. However, if its purely for debugging or prototype code, you could also pipe the output to std::cout's sibling, std::cerr, which is unbuffered to begin with. This means you do not need to call flush explicitly and you do not need to add an endl to your output.

Answer (score -2):

Try Sleep() instead of sleep()